# ReactJS paginated component with React Router

Tags: javascript, react.js

I've recently started journey with ReactJS and to begin with I wanted to try something a bit more complex - paginated list of elements with back functionality enabled.
Below are two main components that I'd like to get feedback about. Especially `PagedListings`.

```
import './App.css';
import PagedListings from './components/PagedListings';
import ScrollToTop from './components/ScrollToTop';
import React from "react";
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
    <ScrollToTop>
       <Route path={["/", "/:page"]} component={PagedListings}/>
    </ScrollToTop>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And the actual component executing planned task

```
import React, { useMemo } from "react";
import ListingsContainer from "./ListingsContainer";
import Pagination from "@material-ui/lab/Pagination";
import { useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const LISTINGS = ["Rec1", "Rec2", "Rec3",
  "Rec4", "Rec5", "Rec6", "Rec7", "Rec8",
  "Rec9", "Rec10",];
const DEFAULT_PAGE = 1;
const MAX_PAGE_COUNT = 10;

function PagedListings(props) {
  const history = useHistory();
  const location = useLocation();
  const urlParams = useMemo(() => {
    return new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  }, [location.search]);

  const handleChange = (
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement> | null,
    newPage: number
  ) => {
    let oneBasedNewPage = newPage;

    urlParams.set("page", oneBasedNewPage.toString());
    updateURL();
  };

  const updateURL = () => {
    history.push({
      pathname: location.pathname,
      search: `?${urlParams}`,
    });
  };

  function getPageNumber() {
    let newPage = parseInt(urlParams.get("page")) || DEFAULT_PAGE;
    return newPage <= MAX_PAGE_COUNT ? newPage : MAX_PAGE_COUNT;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <ListingsContainer listings={LISTINGS.slice(0, getPageNumber())} />
      <Pagination
        count={MAX_PAGE_COUNT}
        defaultPage={DEFAULT_PAGE}
        page={getPageNumber()}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default PagedListings;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks quite reasonable. There are only a few small things I notice:

- Indent the JSX in `App` a bit more: `ScrollToTop` is a child of `Router`, so it should be indented further, not on the same level as `Router`. (It doesn't really make a difference here, but it's good to be consistent, and could be an improvement if that section ever got more complicated)
- [Avoid `let`, prefer `const`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278652/how-much-should-i-be-using-let-vs-const-in-es6) - ESLint rule [here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-const).
- Or, in the case of `oneBasedNewPage`, consider defining the *argument* with that name instead of creating a new variable - and maybe call it `oneIndexed`, not `oneBased`:

  ```
  const handleChange = (
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement> | null,
    oneIndexedNewPage: number
  ) => {
  ```
- `URLSearchParams` does not differentiate between numbers and strings.

  ```
  urlParams.set("page", oneBasedNewPage.toString());
  ```

  can be

  ```
  urlParams.set("page", oneIndexedNewPage);
  ```

  if you wish.
- Consider if using `Math.min` might be clearer than the conditional operator:

  ```
  function getPageNumber() {
    const newPage = parseInt(urlParams.get("page")) || DEFAULT_PAGE;
    return Math.min(newPage, MAX_PAGE_COUNT);
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your review and all of the suggestions. I haven't been aware of the fact to use const instead of let in place you suggested.